# Extracting specific information from data

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval

How can i convert a data format like:

```
James Smith was born on November 17, 1948
```

into something like

```
("James Smith", DOB, "November 17, 1948")
```

without having to rely on positional index of strings

I have tried the following

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

new = "James Smith was born on November 17, 1948"
sentences = word_tokenize(new)
sentences = pos_tag(sentences)
grammar = "Chunk: {<NNP*><NNP*>}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(sentences)
print(result)
```

How to proceed further to get the output in desired fromat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a regular expressions.
The regex `(\S+)\s(\S+)\s\bwas born on\b\s(\S+)\s(\S+),\s(\S+)` will match and return data from specifically the string format above.

Here's it in action: https://regex101.com/r/W2ykKS/1

Regex in python:

```
import re

regex = r"(\S+)\s(\S+)\s\bwas born on\b\s(\S+)\s(\S+),\s(\S+)"
test_str = "James Smith was born on November 17, 1948"

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

# group 0 in a regex is the input string

print(matches.group(1)) # James
print(matches.group(2)) # Smith
print(matches.group(3)) # November
print(matches.group(4)) # 17
print(matches.group(5)) # 1948
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string with 'was born on' after that trim the spaces and assign to name and dob